# How do we write If (Condtion) do (X and Y) else (do A and B) in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Currently I have a condition:

```
Conditions:
    IsBeta: !Equals [!Ref Stage, "beta"]
```

a mapping:

```
Mappings:
  ABCMap:
    beta:
      Role1: "arn:aws::iam::...",
      Role1-Test: "arn:aws::iam::...",
      Role2: ""arn:aws::iam::...",
      Role2-Test: "arn:aws::iam::..."
    prod:
      Role1: "arn:aws::iam::...",
      Role2: "arn:aws::iam::..."
```

and a partial part of a Resource Policy:

```
ResourcePolicy:
    CustomStatements:
    - Action: ['execute-api:Invoke']
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
        AWS:
            - !FindInMap [ IAMRoleMap, !Ref Stage, Role1 ]
            - !FindInMap [ IAMRoleMap, !Ref Stage, Role2 ]
            - Fn::If:
                - IsBeta
                - - !FindInMap [ ABCMap, !Ref Stage, Role1-Test ]
                - {Ref: 'AWS::NoValue'}
            - Fn::If:
                - IsBeta
                - - !FindInMap [ ABCMap, !Ref Stage, Role2-Test ]
                - {Ref: 'AWS::NoValue'}
        Resource: "arn::aws..."
```

How do I combine them into one "if"? Or is there a better way to express that I only need to have Role1-Test and Role2-Test in the resource policy if the stage is beta?

Comment: Can you show more complete example? Where are you trying to use these Ifs?

Comment: Updated with more complete example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put all your principles in one big `Fn::If`:

```
ResourcePolicy:
    CustomStatements:
    - Action: ['execute-api:Invoke']
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS:
            Fn::If:
                - IsBeta
                - - !FindInMap [ IAMRoleMap, !Ref Stage, Role1 ]
                  - !FindInMap [ IAMRoleMap, !Ref Stage, Role2 ]
                  - !FindInMap [ ABCMap, !Ref Stage, Role1-Test ]
                  - !FindInMap [ ABCMap, !Ref Stage, Role2-Test ]
                - - !FindInMap [ IAMRoleMap, !Ref Stage, Role1 ]
                  - !FindInMap [ IAMRoleMap, !Ref Stage, Role2 ]
            Resource: "arn::aws..."
```